# Hidden HTML5 video copied to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-video

I'm working on a project and I need to make it harder to download HTML5 video. The method I plan to use, includes the need to dynamically create a `video` element (not added to the page) using javascript, and write frames from that to a canvas on the page. Can you give me some pointers on how to do this?

Comment: check out https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder - it does basically exactly what you're trying to do. use it for inspiration.

Comment: @LouisK thanks for the link, but I'm not sure how that helps me. What I'm trying to do is copy frames from a `video` element that **isn't actually on the page** to a `canvas` element that *is*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it harder to copy videos you are basically looking for DRM'ed HTML5 videos

There is a HTML5 standard for it and it is called [Encrypted Media Extensions (EME)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypted_Media_Extensions). All major browsers support it.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any tips on how to implement it? Also, and correct me if I'm wrong, it looks like Firefox doesn't support it yet. How can I overcome that?

Comment: If it's not there at least it's on its way http://www.ghacks.net/2014/05/14/mozilla-implement-encrypted-media-extensions-firefox/

Comment: I'd suggest opening another question "How to implement EME"

Comment: It is there http://techcrunch.com/2015/05/12/mozilla-launches-a-new-firefox-version-without-drm-support/